# yoast seo plugin - remove bulk title and description editor menu from non-admins

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast

Is there a way to remove the yoast-seo-plugin's bulk title and description editor menu from the non-admins. It is an awesome feature but I would like my users to keep off from it. I am using the very latest versions of wp and the plugin.

[image]

---

I am trying a few variations of this code, but does not seem to be working.

```
if ( ! current_user_can('create_users') ) {

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'nonadmin_remove_bulk_menu', 999 );

    function nonadmin_remove_bulk_menu() {
    remove_menu_page('page=wpseo_bulk-title-editor.php');
  }
}
```

Comment: Search term: Adminimize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoast SEO uses capabilities ([WordPress docs on roles and capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)) to determine whether users are allowed to bulk edit tiles and descriptions. The name of the capability used for this is `wpseo_bulk_edit`.

By default, Yoast SEO adds this capability to the administrator, editor, author and contributor roles. To remove this capability from all roles except for the administrator roles, it is enough to call `remove_cap` on all other roles. To remove a capability from a role, you first need to fetch the role object:

```
 $role = get_role( $rolename );
 $role->remove_cap( $cap );
```

`remove_cap` needs to be called only once: capability settings for roles are saved to the options table.

Thus, calling this once would to the trick:

```
$roles = array(
    'editor',
    'author',
    'contributor'
);

foreach ( $roles as $rolename ) {
    $role = get_role( $rolename );

    if ( $role ) {
        $role->remove_cap( 'wpseo_bulk_edit' );
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

On (manual) activation of the plugin, the capability will automatically be added to these user roles. Therefore, it would be useful to use the `wpseo_bulk_edit_roles` (explained in the answer by @fischi) in addition to calling the snippet above once:

```
function myplugin_wpseo_bulk_edit_roles( $roles ) {
    return array( 'administrator' );
}

add_filter( 'wpseo_bulk_edit_roles', 'myplugin_wpseo_bulk_edit_roles' );
```

Comment: Thanks that solved it. I did not know about the `wpseo_bulk_edit` handle.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the filter `wpseo_submenu_pages` for that. The plugin provides an `array` of all used submenupages, and lists the capability someone needs to access the certain page.

The Submenupageitem `wpseo_bulk-title-editor` has the values (for example):

```
[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => wpseo_dashboard //parentmenupage
        [1] => Yoast WordPress SEO: Bulk Title Editor // Page Title
        [2] => Bulk Title Editor // Menu Title
        [3] => wpseo_bulk_edit // Capability needed
        [4] => wpseo_bulk-title-editor // Page to load
        [5] => Array  // some other stuff, did not check by now.
            (
                [0] => WPSEO_Admin Object
                    (
                    )

                [1] => load_page
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => WPSEO_Admin Object
                            (
                            )

                        [1] => bulk_edit_options
                    )

            )

    )
```

From that, you can see two different possibilities:

### User Management

**removing the capability `wpseo_bulk_edit` from non-admins**

The standard roles having this capability are:

```
$roles = array(
    'administrator',
    'editor',
    'author',
    'contributor',
);
```

You can filter the function to `wpseo_submenu_pages`:

```
function f711_add_WPSEO_bulk_capabilities( $roles ) {
    return array( 'administrator' ); // skip all other roles
}

add_filter( 'wpseo_bulk_edit_roles', 'f711_add_WPSEO_bulk_capabilities', 999999, 1 );
```

Unfortunately, this filter is only used on `activate` and `deactivate` of the Plugin, so you will have to do that. *Only hook the function when you activate the plugin - otherwise you will just remove the capability from the filtered roles!*

Afterwards, your filter has to stay active, as you will need to filter the roles everytime you do an activation of the plugin.

### Changing the capability needed to bulk Edit

This is another solution, although the first one is the better one, IMO.

You could loop through the menupages, and set the capavility of the `wpseo_bulk-title-editor` to `manage_options`.

```
function f711_remove_WPSEO_admin_pages( $adminpages ) {

    foreach( $adminpages as &$thispage ) {

        if ( $thispage[4] == 'wpseo_bulk-description-editor' || $thispage[4] == 'wpseo_bulk-title-editor' ) { // check the page
            $thispage[3] = 'manage_options'; // set the needed capability
        }

    }
    return $adminpages;

} 
add_filter( 'wpseo_submenu_pages', 'f711_remove_WPSEO_admin_pages', 999999, 1 );
```

Both work great - the benefit of the second solution is that it is capability-driven, whereas the first solution depends on the roles. The benefit of the first solution is that you have to run the functions only once, and not everytime the admin is called, so it is better when thinking about performance.

**EDIT**

Of course, as @engelen mentioned, you can also just remove the capability - but it will get added again everytime you do a manual activation to the Plugin.

Comment: very well explained. I am gonna keep this handy, thank you.

Comment: The capability will not be added every time the plugin is updated. The function `wpseo_add_capabilities` is called on plugin activation (via `register_activation_hook`, which is not called on plugin upgrade) and on upgrading the plugin from a version below 1.5.0 (which is the version in which bulk title and description was introduced). However, manual plugin activation will cause the capabilities to be added again. I've updated my answer, thanks!

Comment: @engelen oh sorry, I was totally on the wrong foot there. You are right of course, activation hook is not called on upgrade. I updated my answer to provide the correct solution as well.